# matlab regular expression

Tags: regex, matlab

In the following string: `quantity = 100;` I would like to use a regex in order to get `100`.

Why doesn't the following regex return `100`??

`regexp('quantity=100;','(?=\w*\s*\=\s*)[^]+(?=\s*;$)','match','once')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a negative look ahead regex in the beginning, try this:

`regexp('quantity=100;','(?<=\w*\s*\=\s*)[^]+(?=\s*;$)','match','once')`

or

`regexp( 'quantity=100;', '(?<=^.*\=\s*)(.*)(?=\s*;$)', 'match', 'once' )` which is much simpler

Comment: I have never seen [^]+ actually compile without errors. It must be a Matlab thing.

Answer (score 7):

The regex to match any digit is `\d`. So if your strings are only of the form `text=numbers`, then the following will work.

```
digits = regexp( 'quantity=100;', '\d', 'match');
result = [digits{:}]

result = 
         '100'
```

Note that MATLAB returns a cell array of matches. So you can't use `'once'` because it will return only `1`.

Comment: This can be simplified to `result = regexp( 'quantity=100;', '\d+', 'match')`